# Which is faster: Reading from console or writing to file and reading?

Tags: java, multithreading, io, parallel-processing

I have a list of very large( ~ 300 mb) files in a directory, that need to be filtered using an awk script, multiple times, using different search parameter each time.
I have written a program which uses uses fixedThreadPool executor to spawn multiple threads, and the task implementation inside each thread is such that it creates a new Runtime() object and executes the awk script through a new Process which uses the bash shell to execute the script

Here's a sample code:

Class MultiThreadingImpl:

```
public class MultiThreadingImpl {
    static List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<File>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);//creating a pool of 5 threads  

        File logsDir = new File("TestFilesDir");
        getLogFiles(logsDir);
        String[] searchKeys = {"123456","PAT1"};

        for (int i = 0; i < filesList.size() ; i++) {  
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(filesList.get(i),searchKeys[i]);  
            executor.execute(worker);//calling execute method of ExecutorService  
          }  
        executor.shutdown();  

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {   }  

        System.out.println("Finished all threads"); 

    }

    private static void getLogFiles(File logsDir) {
        assert(logsDir.isDirectory());

        for(File f : logsDir.listFiles(
                new  FilenameFilter(){
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

                        return !name.endsWith("_result.txt");
                    }

                }
                )){
            filesList.add(f);
        }

    }
}
```

Class WorkerThread :

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {  
    private String outputFile; 
    private String searchKey;
    private File logFile;

    public WorkerThread(File logFile,String searchKey){  
        this.logFile = logFile; 
        this.searchKey = searchKey;
        this.outputFile = String.format(logFile.getName().replace(".txt", "") + "_result.txt");
    }  

    public void run() {  
        int res = 0;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String awkRegex = new StringBuilder("'/([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{2})[[:space:]][[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]][0-9]{4}/{n=0}")
                            .append("/"+searchKey+"/").append("{n=1} n' ").toString();
        String awkCommand = new StringBuilder("/usr/bin/awk ").append(awkRegex)
                .append(logFile.getAbsolutePath()).append(" &> ").append("/TestFilesDir").append(outputFile).toString();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":: Command : " + awkCommand);
        String[] cmdList =  { "/bin/bash", "-c", awkCommand};

        try {
            final Process process = runtime.exec(cmdList);

            res = process.waitFor();

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));


            while (stdInput.readLine() != null) {
                //Emptying stream
            }

            StringBuffer strerror = new StringBuffer();
            String serror = null;
            while ((serror = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                strerror.append(serror + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":: Process Exit value: " + res);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }  

}
```

Here I have an option of choosing to write to a unique output file for each individual input file and then merging them using `cat` and finally read the merged file.

And I also have the option of reading the output from each Process' output stream into a string and merge all strings.

Which mechanism is faster?

Also suggest if there are ways to make the whole thing even faster?

Comment: Why not try it yourself and see which is faster?

Answer (score 0):

From an operating point of view: That shouldn't make a difference. In fact, with the `splice` syscall that many modern OSes have, it really shouldn't have *any* overhead to do either. However, you're doing some things in Java that probably have quite some overhead (the whole buffered Reader business: why?)

> Also suggest if there are ways to make the whole thing even faster?

Why call a shell from Java that calls `awk` which parses your expression to filter things?

Just use a string/regex engine in Java.

Java does have some speed limitations itself, but I believe they might not be severe; there's some overhead in the `BufferedStreamReader(InputStreamReader)` construct, so if you're really squeezing the last bit of performance out of this, you'd certainly just go ahead and implement all this in native code; again, I don't believe you'd win much compared to just using what tools Java brings.

Algorithmically, what you're doing is bad: Go through each file *once*, do all the filtering at once, don't go through every file multiple times. Spawning a new process unnecessarily also has additional overhead.

Multithreading doesn't help here. You're definitely not CPU bound, but IO bound, and multithreading can't increase the bandwidth of your storage – on the contrary, it'd typically even break linear access and make things slower.

This all feels like it'd take 10 lines of shell script rather than a complex multithreaded Java application, and would be faster to start and execute.

Comment: **You're definitely not CPU bound** 
Do you mean to say that the filtering done by awk is not cpu bound?
If so where can I learn how to write those 10 lines of shell script?

Comment: you basically already wrote them. Just write down all the AWK calls you're executing from Java directly into a text file. I mean, I assumed that you're familiar with `bash` since you're using it to execute a script in your java program!

Comment: why on earth should such a simple operation like looking for these trivial string patterns be CPU bound? Have you considered how slow permanent storage is compared to a CPU? Even if you put all these files into a RAM buffer (which your OS does for you), you get memory bandwidth limited, most likely.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't cpu bound. But if I have the data on a SSD, I guess multithreading will help speed up the process, doesn't it?

Comment: Seriously, I'm getting a bit tired of repeating my answer. No. An SSD is still significantly slower than your CPU, and thus having multiple threads doesn't help, and prefetching happens linearly, which means that multithreading hurts, too (though not as badly as for HDDs)

Answer (score -1):

- don't use Runtime() and the 'awk' script.  instead translate the 'awk' script to Java. Even if the Java version would run slightly slower than 'awk', mixing both 'awk' and Java just complicates the program.
- also, don't create one thread per file to be processed (there is an overhead every time that you create a new thread).  Instead, use only a fixed number of threads and with some logic divide the files evenly among those threads.  Each thread will be processing a few files sequentially.  (it you need even more speed, then put the files in some shared filesystem - for example S3 - and then process your files using multiple computers.

Comment: for medium sized files (like, basically, I'd consider 300MB to be the lower end of "medium sized"), awk is bound to be much faster than implementing that regex in Java – Java's really not optimized for string operations. I'd agree on "use a library that does the regexing (but does it in native code)", not on "try to be faster than a heavily optimized native program's string operation in hand-implemented Java".